# Boostrap Select - How to return a variable from JQuery as the preselected option

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, select, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to return a variable from JQuery and have it as the preselected option in a [Boostrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)?

I have an Update Form inside a Modal and I would like, since I already have found the variable I need inside JQuery, to add this variable as the preselected option in the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="department_id2">Department Name List</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span></span>
        <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="department_id2" name="department_id2" data-live-search="true">
            <option value="name1">Name1</option>
            <option value="name2">Name2</option>
            <option value="name3">Name3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the JQuery value is 'name2'

You would do....

```
var selectedVal = 'name2';
$('#department_id2').val(selectedVal);
```

This is assuming that the value you have in JQuery exists as one of the options in your select. IF NOT... then you can add it first and then select it:

```
var selectedVal = 'name2';
$('#department_id2').append($('<option>').text(selectedVal).attr('value', selectedVal);
$('#department_id2').val(selectedVal);
```